# How to exclude cells with dates?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

In this table, I have to filter 2 column. For the column “3” (C) , I have **to exclude** all the cells with date for the filter. The others cells are with string or empty.
The problem, I only finding was to filter by giving the value we want to see, but in my case, it’s not possible because the text can be different, so I can bor ask to filter exact value.

How can I do to exclude in this colum all the cells with a dates ? or just ask to display only the cells with TEXT FORMAT ?

Thank you !

```
Sub Filter_EM
'
' Filter_EM Makro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AV$3224").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="EM"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AV$3224").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Text1", "Text2", "Text3", _
        "Text4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you aware you can record macros? If you execute the autofilter by hand and you record that action, what do you get?

Comment: The code I put in my request is coming from the Macro Recording.

Answer (score 0):

If you data looks like this

[image]

Add a helper column with the formula `=ISTEXT(A:A)`, and filter in that helper column for `CStr(True)`:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$17").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=CStr(True)
```

> *Sorry for the german screenshot, `FALSCH` means `FALSE` and `WAHR` means `TRUE` here.*

Comment: Thanks. Not a problem, i m living in Germany :)
The problem is that this is not my file and I have no right to add or modify or add any column. I have only the right to extract or look at datas from it.

Comment: @Meriole Well, `AutoFilter` has no such ability. So either you write your own code to hide what you don't need or you extract the data to your own sheet and add that helper column.